# Kendo Scheduler event is not getting updated after resize

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo scheduler with transport function.  Below is the url

http://runner.telerik.io/fullscreen/IgOba

Here in this scheduler when I try to resize the event or move the event event widget is getting resized/moved for a fraction of second and then comes back to the previous stage. But the data is getting updated in backend(it is not there in above example) if I refresh the page its showing the updated event widget.  From the Kendo UI demo (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index) I removed the create and delete event from transport and made update as a javascript function. With this small change the event widget failing to get updated the size...

Please help me if you know any help is appreciated.

Comment: hmm, am i missing something here? but your demo works fine

Comment: edited a bit here http://runner.telerik.io/fullscreen/IgOba/2    I added e.success and its working fine now

Comment: I know this question is "old" but I have the same problem.Can you explain me please where did you added `e.success`? In your linked code I can not see it